# How to create conditional copy in Ansible based on network (subnet) membership

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to copy one version of a file to a server if it has an interface in a specific subnet, or a different version if it does not have an interface in that subnet. Below is a working, but I think less than optimal solution. I'm hoping there is a better way that meets the following criteria...

- stays dynamic (use facts, I don't want to have to manually set variables for every server and manually create groups for servers in and not in the subnet)
- less repetitive (could it be handled in one task?)
- not have to list out every possible interface name (eg. eth0, eth1, ..., bond0, bond1, ... etc)

working version...

```
- name: copy file version 1 to server
  copy:
    src: files/myfile.vs1
    dest: /etc/myfile
  when: (ansible_eth0.network == "192.168.0.0") or
        (ansible_eth1.network == "192.168.0.0") or
        (ansible_eth2.network == "192.168.0.0")
        ...

- name: copy file version 2 to server
  copy:
    src: files/myfile.vs2
    dest: /etc/myfile
  when: (ansible_eth0.network != "192.168.0.0") and
        (ansible_eth1.network != "192.168.0.0") and
        (ansible_eth2.network != "192.168.0.0")
        ...
```

Comment: This actually fails if the when line contains an interface that the server doesn't have

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some jinja2 ninja tricks and here you are:

```
- copy:
    src: >-
         {{ (
              ansible_interfaces |
              map('regex_replace','^','ansible_') |
              map('extract',hostvars[inventory_hostname]) |
              selectattr('ipv4','defined') |
              selectattr('ipv4.network','equalto','192.168.0.0') |
              list |
              count > 0
            ) | ternary('files/myfile.vs1','files/myfile.vs2')
         }}
    dest: /etc/myfile
```

Explanation:

- take a list of available interfaces from `ansible_interfaces`
- prepend all interfaces' names with `ansible_` to become (`ansible_eth0`, etc)
- extract all interfaces' facts from host own `hostvars`
- select only those interfaces where `ipv4` is defined
- select only those interfaces where `ipv4.network` equals to `192.168.0.0`
- convert to list
- count
- if there is one or more such interface return `files/myfile.vs1`
- return `files/myfile.vs2` otherwise

P.S. `>-` is used to define multiline string and strip any newlines, otherwise `src` will be set to `files/myfile.vs2\n`.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works great. Just a note for anyone else, I had to update my version of jinja2. selectattr was added in version 2.7