# Complex filtering in Ansible/Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am pretty new to Jinja2, and I'm wondering how to achieve this.

Say I have the following `vars`:

```
---
servers:
  192.168.0.1:
    names:
      - foo.example.com
      - foo
    exports:
      data:
        foo1: /disks/foo1
        foo2: /disks/foo2
  192.168.0.2:
    ...
```

I want to create a symlink `/data/foo1` to `/disks/foo1` and `/data/foo2` to `/disks/foo2`, but only on `foo` server; on other servers, make symlinks to their respective exports. So I thought `file status=link with_items=...` would be the correct thing to do. In Python, I can get the array I need using the following logic:

```
[
    { 'mount': mount, 'export': export }
    for ip, server in servers.iteritems()
    if ansible_hostname in server['names']
    and 'exports' in server
    and 'data' in server['exports']
    for mount, export in server['exports']['data'].iteritems()'
]
```

I don't know how to do this in Jinja2. I wanted to do something like

```
{{ servers | select('ansible_hostname in self.names') | ... }}
```

but that doesn't work. Would I need to create a plugin for this logic? Or is my approach all wrong and I should rethink the structure of my `servers` data?

Comment: Why not just loop over `servers[ansible_hostname].exports.data`?

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov: because I don't know which form `ansible_hostname` takes. Now that I say it out lout it sounds stupid - it is probably what I put into `inventory`, right? I'll try and play with that tomorrow; in the meantime I'm still curious about complex transformations in Jinja2.

Comment: Usually you want to use `inventory_hostname` variable – it is what you use as host name in inventory. `servers[ansible_hostname]` will access `servers`' key with name of `ansible_hostname`'s value. Just for curiosity, you can check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40395995/2795592) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40036807/2795592).

Comment: Welp, no more answers. @KonstantinSuvorov: If you submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from my comment:

Usually you want to use `inventory_hostname` variable – it is what you use as host name in inventory.
`servers[ansible_hostname]` will access `servers`' key with name of `ansible_hostname`'s value.

Just for curiosity, you can check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40395995/2795592) (complex filter chain) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40036807/2795592) (runtime object construction).